# Detecting first 20 chars in string in mark_safe()

Tags: python, django

How can I add non breaking space(`&nbsp`) after first 20 chars of `my_string`?

```
my_string = "12345678 912345678 15235213523 23512351235"

test = mark_safe(re.sub(
        #after first 20 chars add &nbsp,
        r' \1&nbsp;',
        my_string,
        flags=re.UNICODE,
    ))
```

Comment: Can you please add input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z="12345678 912345678 15235213523 23512351235"
print re.sub(r"^(.{20})",r"\1&nbsp;",z,flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 2):

For adding `&nbsp;` after first 20 characters alone, you can try -

```
my_string = "12345678 912345678 15235213523 23512351235"
print(my_string[:20] + "&nbsp;" + my_string[20:])
>> '12345678 912345678 1&nbsp;5235213523 23512351235'
```

Use `my_string[:20] + "&nbsp;" + my_string[20:]` where you want.